# Trouble formatting .join() separators

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Working on a twitter bootstrap wizard page and outputting selected check-box values to next tab-pane. Because there can be multiple selections (ie. :checked), I'm using map function and join(). I'm trying to wrap each output in a `<li>` but the first item does not get wrapped -- only every item after the 1st.

Eg.

Checkbox 1
`<li>`Checkbox 2`</li>`
`<li>`Checkbox 3`</li>`

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
            onNext: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                if (index == 1) {
                    if (!$('.selection:checked').val()) {
                        alert('Please select a solution to try');
                        $('.selection').focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                $('#showSelection').html($('.selection:checked').map(function() {
                    return $(this).val();
                }).get().join('<li>'));
            }
        });
```

Not sure if I should be using a different method? Or... if there is a way to pre-append and force a separator "wrap" around all selections. Any insight/clarity would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Arnelle! I now have a better understanding of why the separator was functioning the way it was ;) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
$('#showSelection').html('<li>' + $('.selection:checked').map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).get().join('</li><li>') + '</li>);
```

This is because the separator for the join will only be added in between the elements, not before and after them so your first element will not have an opening `li` tag and the last will not have a closing `li` tag.